# Group radio buttons without list

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm new in programming and this is my first question, I hope I did it according to the rules.
I want to place radio buttons and next to them text boxes. I understand that I can't do it with radio buttons list. Like this:
[Radio Buttons on the right side of the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgBhw.png)
What is the best way to do it and how to group them? Further I want to check which of the buttons is checked and save this information.
I will appreciate any suggestion for the correct way to do it.

Comment: You can try radio buttons GroupName property .

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to achieve and where you are having trouble. Is there a reason you can't use a `RadioButtonList`? You would have to manually do the mapping between the selected RadioButton and the text in the corresponding TextBox. I don't think there is a built in way to do that.

Comment: Now I use radio button and GroupName, but in my code behind I use if-else structure to find out which button is check an d map it to the textbox. I thought maybe there is more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

You can use the `GroupName` property of RadioButton to do so ...

Example:

```
<asp:RadioButton id="Radio1" GroupName="radio" runat="server"/>
<asp:RadioButton id="Radio2" GroupName="radio" runat="server"/>
<asp:RadioButton id="Radio3" GroupName="radio" runat="server"/>
```

Then you can access this RadioButtons in your code behind .

For further reference [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This May Help You To Put Radio Button with textbox using input group bootstrap

```
<link href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  
    <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="radio" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
              </span>
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                Your Text
              </span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button">
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks very good. I was looking for the way to link it to the code behind.